# get value of checked radio button with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I want to get the value of selected radio field on change. If the selected value is `Admin` I want to disable the group of fields with ID `permissions_forms` and all those checkboxes inside it should be checked.  Otherwise,if the value is not `Admin` they should be enabled.

I tried to get the value but the function of change is not working in my case.
Can somebody help me, please? Here is  [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JRd9X/51/#&togetherjs=kbLnjdgDGk)

Here is HTML code:

```
<ul class="radio" id="role">
  <li>
    <input id="role-0" name="role" type="radio" value="User">
    <label for="role-0">User</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input checked="" id="role-1" name="role" type="radio" value="Admin">
    <label for="role-1">Admin</label>
  </li>
</ul>
<br/><br/><br/><br/>
<ul class="checkbox" id="permissions_forms">
  <li>
    <input checked="" id="diagnsosis_forms-0" name="diagnsosis_forms" type="checkbox">
    <label for="diagnsosis_forms-0"> Checkbox enable when admin selected</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input checked="" id="diagnsosis_forms-1" name="diagnsosis_forms" type="checkbox" >
    <label for="diagnsosis_forms-1"> Checkbox enable when admin selected</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And the jQuery code:

```
$('#role').change(function() {
  selected = $('input[name=role]:checked').val();
  if (selected == "Admin") {
    alert('Admin');
    $("#permissions_forms :input").attr("disabled", true);
    $("#permissions_forms").parent().siblings().find(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
  }
  else{
  $("#permissions_forms :input").attr("disabled", false);
  }
});
```

Comment: Side note, IDs **must** be unique

Comment: You don't want `.attr('checked')` you want `.is(':checked')`

Comment: or instead of attr use prop.

Answer (score 1):

**Class or Id?**

Do not assign the same id to multiple elements. Id should be unique. Use class instead.

```
<div id="im-unique">Earth</div>

<div class="im-not-unique">Star 1</div>
<div class="im-not-unique">Star 2</div>
```

**How to toggle the properties `disabled` and `checked` with jquery?**

> If the selected value is Admin I want to disable the group of fields with ID permissions_forms and all those checkboxes inside it should be checked.

`$checkboxes.prop({ "disabled": true, 'checked': true});` will make the checkboxes disabled and checked.

**Why `prop` not `attr`?**

from jquery's doc:

> To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the .prop() method.

```js
function onChange() {
  var selected = $('input[name=role]:checked').val();
  var $checkboxes = $("#diagnsosis_forms-0, #diagnsosis_forms-1", "#permissions_forms");
  if (selected == "Admin") {
    $checkboxes.prop({ "disabled": true, 'checked': true});
  }
  else {
    $checkboxes.prop("disabled", false);
  }
}
onChange()
$('#role').change(onChange);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="radio" id="role">
  <li>
    <input id="role-0" name="role" type="radio" value="User" class="">
    <label for="role-0">User</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input checked="" id="role-1" name="role" type="radio" value="Admin">
    <label for="role-1">Admin</label>
  </li>
</ul>
<br/><br/><br/><br/>
<ul class="checkbox" id="permissions_forms">
  <li>
    <input checked="" id="diagnsosis_forms-0" name="diagnsosis_forms" type="checkbox">
    <label for="diagnsosis_forms-0"> Checkbox enable when admin selected</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input checked="" id="diagnsosis_forms-1" name="diagnsosis_forms" type="checkbox" >
    <label for="diagnsosis_forms-1"> Checkbox enable when admin selected</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and your time. I have only small detail since on the checkbox I can't add a class: diagnsosis_forms-0, and without it the code doesn't work? any idea?

Comment: updated. you can use `$('#id')` to get elements by id, or `$('.class')` by class.

Comment: Nope. Pls look at the code carefully. now they are `id="diagnsosis_forms-0"` and `id="diagnsosis_forms-1"`, not longer classes.